# Characterization of convex differentiable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I am trying to prove the following statement

> Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function whose gradient exists at any point. Then for any $x, y$ we have $f(y) - f(x) \geq \langle \nabla f(x), y - x \rangle$.

without geometric interpretations as hyperplanes and such. I take as definition of convexity of $f$ that $\{(x, r) \ | \ f(x) \leq r\}$ is convex.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(t)=f((1-t)x+ty)$ for $0\leq t \leq 1$. Since $f$ is convex, $g$ too is convex, so $g'$ exists and is non-decreasing. We have by the Mean Value Theorem:

$$ f(y)-f(x)=g(1)-g(0)=g'(c)\geq g'(0) $$

for some $c\in (0,1)$. If we differentiate $g$ at $0$, we get

$$ g'(0)=df_{x}(y-x)=\langle \nabla f(x),y-x \rangle. $$

As for why $g$ is convex, we have that $h\colon t\in \mathbb{R}\mapsto (1-t)x+ty=x+t(y-x)$ is an affine function (i.e. $h(t)-h(t')=(t-t')(y-x)$ is linear in $t-t'$), so $g=f\circ h$ is convex. This is because for $t,t'\in \mathbb{R}$, $\mu \in [0,1]$, we have $h((1-\mu)t+\mu t')=(1-\mu)h(t)+\mu h(t')$ (by direct computation), so
$$ f(h((1-\mu)t+\mu t'))=f((1-\mu)h(t)+\mu h(t'))\leq (1-\mu)f(h(t))+\mu f(h(t')) $$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I'm having some trouble showing that $g(t)$ is convex. We want to show that $g(\lambda t_1 + (1 - \lambda)t_2) \leq \lambda g(t_1) + (1 - \lambda) g(t_2)$ right?

Comment: Yes. By expanding the left side it should be easy to prove. Alternatively, observe that $g$ is the composition of a convex function with a linear (hence convex) function, so it must be convex.

Comment: I tried expanding and didn't really get anywhere. How does that last argument work? Convex functions are not closed under composition, take for example $e^{-x}$ composed with itself.

Comment: And coming to think of it, I don't think convexity for functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^p$ is defined.

Comment: What you said is true, my bad. Let me try to rewrite everything.

Comment: If you have any problems with the assertion about $h$, let me know.

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much for your help!